# Linq to objects from Untyped Datatable Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: datatable, linq-to-objects

I am completely at a loss for why linq is throwing an Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String' exception. The code is part of a generic function meant to pull the DataTextField and DataValueField out of an untyped DataTable and place them in a list of KeyValuePair(of string, string). I added a for each loop above the linq query to step through each item, and that worked fine. The data returned for the DataValueField is numeric, but its in an untyped set. I tried ToString() on the fields, not sure what to even try next. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Private Function GetCurrentBoundControlDT(ByVal StoredProcedure As String, ByVal ParamList As String, ByVal DataTextField As String, ByVal DataValueField As String) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim BoundControlDataList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = Nothing

        If ParamList.Trim <> String.Empty Then
            StoredProcedure = String.Format("{0} {1}", StoredProcedure, ParamList)
        End If

        ds = RG.GetDS(StoredProcedure)

        If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            dt = ds.Tables(0)

            'This works fine
            For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Dim test1 As String = r(DataTextField)
                Dim test2 As String = r(DataValueField)
                Dim kv As New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(test1, test2)
            Next
            'Blows up here...
            BoundControlDataList = (From ThisTable In dt.AsEnumerable() _
                    Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(ThisTable.Field(Of String)(DataTextField).ToString(), _
                                               ThisTable.Field(Of String)(DataValueField).ToString())).ToList()
        End If

        Return BoundControlDataList
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. It's not exactly pretty, but works. It seems like (of string) is not so much a cast as a suggestion. I guess (of object) should handle any primitive data correctly and wrapping Convert.ToString() around the field did the trick. The following change is what did it...

```
            BoundControlDataList = (From t In dt.AsEnumerable() _
                                    Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(Convert.ToString(t.Field(Of Object)(DataTextField).ToString()), _
                                     Convert.ToString(t.Field(Of Object)(DataValueField).ToString()))).ToList()
```